# Failed to load modules Matlab R2019a

Tags: matlab, overlay-scrollbars

I have just installed Matlab R2019a on my Ubuntu 16.04LTS. When I run it from a terminal, I get the following GTK message:

```
Gtk-Message: 18:16:10.235: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: 18:16:10.236: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 18:16:10.247: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

but, the modules are already installed. 
How can I fix it, even though Matlab runs normally? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Re the overlay scrollbar message, you have 3 options:

- Ignore it, as it is harmless; you'll just get normal scrollbars.
- Install overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 so you have the overlay scrollbar module for GTK2 applications.
- Set the env variable GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0 to inhibit trying to load the module.